# Java always give me wrong result with huge numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I wrote this line of code:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(7, 23) % 143);   // 7^23 mod 143
```

I expected the output to be `2` but the output was `93.0`. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Overflow. You need to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Comment: It's not that it's overflowing, it's that `7^23` can't be represented precisely as a double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number "overflows" `double`, which is what `Math.pow()` expects and returns. Use a `BigInteger` instead:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(7)
        .pow(23)
        .mod(BigInteger.valueOf(143))
```

Or in a single step, as suggested by @Felk:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(7)
        .modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(23), BigInteger.valueOf(143))
```

Comment: There's one incorrect statement in your answer: "The number overflows double". Being around 2.7e19, it's well within the `double` range, but can't be expressed with the necessary precision. So the BigInteger solution is the straightforward way to go.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Yes, you're right. I just put that in quotes, as Andy Turner nailed it down already. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The result of `Math.pow` is a `double`, which has 64 bits; 53 of those are mantissa bits. This means that any integer greater than `2^53-1 = 9007199254740991` can't be represented precisely as a double.

7^23 is larger than 2^53-1 (it's just a bit larger than 2^64, actually), so it can't be represented precisely. As such, the result of the `%` is not what you expect.

Use `BigInteger` instead, as [@Costi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323451/3788176) has already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Modular exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) if the intermediate exponentiation result is too large to hold in a variable.

```
System.out.println(powMod(7, 23, 143)); // = 2

// Example from Wikipedia with minor changes
private static int powMod(int base, int exponent, int modulus) {
    if (modulus == 1)
        return 0;

    base %= modulus;
    int result = 1;
    while (exponent > 0) {
        if ((exponent & 1) == 1)
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
```